# Is there a properties number limitation when generating an associated table to a JPA model?

Tags: mysql, jpa, playframework

I am trying to create a model in Play! with over 150 properties. I would like it to automatically generate the corresponding table in my database. 
This is working well with H2 but not with mySQL.
Is there a play! or JPA Or MySQL limitation that is forbidding this kind of action? And if yes, is there a way to pass through it?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a limit of a row being 64k in size.  Some storage engines are less. [MySQL 5.6 Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html)

I don't know what types your columns are, but I think unless specified otherwise, String fields are created quite large by Hibernate.  I think Strings tend to be given a default length of 255.

If you haven't already, check the annotations on your model, and see if there are any Strings without lengths and use the hibernate annotations to define them rather than letting Hibernate guess.

Comment: Excellent solution Gary! I just add a @Column(length=xx) to each property and it's working like a charm now. Thank you!